# Call object's method within template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-studio-2003

I have following code:

```
template<class T>
class TemplateA  : public virtual std::list<T>
{
protected:
    unsigned int iSize;
public:
    unsigned int getSize();
};
/////////////
template<class T>
unsigned int TemplateA<T>::getSize()
{
    return iSize;
}
/////////////
/////////////
/////////////
template<class T>
class TemplateB : public TemplateA<T>
{
public:
    unsigned int calcSize();
};
/////////////
template<class C>
unsigned int TemplateB<C>::calcSize()
{
    iSize = C.getSize;
    return iSize;
}
/////////////
/////////////
/////////////
// Class C (seperate file) has to contain function getSize()
class CMyClass
{
public:
    static const unsigned int getSize = 5;
};
```

This means, within class TemplateB I want to call the getSize method, which the passed class have defined.

I receive the following error message:

```
error C2275: 'C' : illegal use of this type as an expression
while compiling class template member function 'unsigned int TemplateB<C>::calcSize()'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              C=CMyClass
1>          ]
```

I'm quiet sure that this function worked under VS 2003... What's wrong with the method? Maybe a compiler setting? I don't know where to set what :(

Comment: Just as an aside, inheriting from standard containers is discouraged due to their (deliberately) non-virtual destructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should say `this->getSize` or `C::getSize`; this will defer lookup to the second phase when the template arguments are known.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could simplify your code too whilst correcting, all you seem to have done is use C rather than TemplateB so if you do:

```
template<class C>
unsigned int TemplateB<C>::calcSize()
{
    return  c::getSize; //based on getSize being static
}
```

You will save the memory of an extra variable and it should work fine:)

**Addendum:**
Here is a working code snippet using your code as a basis:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class TemplateA  : public virtual std::list<T>
{
protected:
    unsigned int iSize;
public:
    unsigned int getSize();
};

template<class T>
unsigned int TemplateA<T>::getSize()
{
    return iSize;
}

template<class T>
class TemplateB : public TemplateA<T>
{
public:
    unsigned int calcSize();
};

template<class C>
unsigned int TemplateB<C>::calcSize()
{
    return C::getSize;
}

// Class C (seperate file) has to contain function getSize()
class CMyClass
{
public:
    static const unsigned int getSize = 5;
};
int main()
{
    CMyClass classme;
    TemplateB<CMyClass> test ;
    cout <<"Calc size outputs: "<< test.calcSize() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Apologies for the unchecked answer previously.
Hope this one helps!

Comment: This code is plain wrong. The langage here is C++, not a sort of C# or Java.